# startnode.cmd file not recognized

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereumjs, ethereum-classic, geth-debugging, puppeth

When I opened my folder mygethnode in VSC.

There are only two folders named geth and keystore and 4 json files.

.puppeth folder and startnode.cmd file is not there.

How to edit the parameters without startnode.cmd file present